# Overwrite session variable using ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, session-variables

I have created an YouTube search engine that sends video id, title etc. using session. I have created buttons with unique ids for each of them, onclicking which a page is called via ajax and the session is generated using the unique id for that button.

The javascript code is like follows:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function loadXMLSession(videoid, videotitle) {
            var xmlhttp;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {// code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "GenerateDownloadSession.php?videoid=" + videoid + "&videotitle=" + videotitle, true);
            xmlhttp.send();


            //strip off spaces and embed dashes - clean urls
            var downloadtitle = videotitle;
            downloadtitle = downloadtitle.toLowerCase();
            downloadtitle = downloadtitle.replace("-"," ");//strip off dashes with spaces
            downloadtitle = downloadtitle.replace(/ +(?= )/g,'');//replace multiple spaces with one space
            downloadtitle = downloadtitle.replace(/[`~!@#$%^&*()_|+\-=?;:'",.<>\{\}\[\]\\\/]/gi, '');//strip off all special characters from video title
            downloadtitle = downloadtitle.replace(/ /g,"-");//replace spaces with dashes
            downloadtitle = downloadtitle.replace(/-+$|(-)+/g, '$1');//replace multiple dashes with single dash

            var url = window.location.hostname;
            url = "/development"//only for development phase
            url = url+"/download/"+downloadtitle+".html";
            window.location=url;

        }
    </script>
```

The download buttons are coded as follows:

```
echo "<button id=\"downloadbtn\" class=\"btn\" value = \"" . $YouTubeVideoID . "\" onclick=\"loadXMLSession(this.value,'" . $VideoContent['6'] . "')\"><img src=\"" . $HostURLRedirect . "/img/Arrow-Down-icon.png\" alt=\"download\" />&nbsp;Download</button>&nbsp;";
```

The php page called by ajax has simple session creation:

```
session_start();
$videoid = $_GET['videoid'];
$videotitle = $_GET['videotitle'];
$_SESSION['DownloadID'] = $videoid;
$_SESSION['DownloadTitle'] = $videotitle;
$_SESSION['DownloadType'] = "Download";
```

The problem that I am having is, when I click on any of the download button for the first time after opening the browser, it is working well. But when I search again, it is returning the previous session values. I am calling the session function through ajax and passing values to it. And, it should overwrite the session values. But in this case, it is not overwriting the values. How can I overcome this issue? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "GenerateDownloadSession.php?videoid=" + videoid + "&videotitle=" + videotitle, true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

you are doing an **asynchronous** Request, which means, that the javascript continues after *sending* the request, not waiting for it to complete. Most likely it will hit your redirect of your current page to the download **before** the call could change the Session data.

Solution 1.) Make the script synchronous by setting the last parameter to false.

Solution 2.) Move your forward logic into the `onreadystatechange` callback function.

on a side node: why using ajax for this? you could simple pass the parameters appended to the url when forwarding...?

Comment: Changing the request to be synchronous isn't a very good idea. A synchronous request completely blocks the UI thread until the request is complete.

Comment: Thanks sir :) I have changed the idea and made the variable pass using url and it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the GET-Values set when requesting your Script?
Use your Firebug to check what is answered by the PHP-Script. (Network -> you will see the requested file being loaded when your Ajax Request is being started).

Answer (score 0):

you should change the location of you page once you get the ajax response:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
{
       if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
          document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;

        var downloadtitle = videotitle;
        downloadtitle = downloadtitle.toLowerCase();
        downloadtitle = downloadtitle.replace("-"," ");//strip off dashes with spaces
        downloadtitle = downloadtitle.replace(/ +(?= )/g,'');//replace multiple spaces with one space
        downloadtitle = downloadtitle.replace(/[`~!@#$%^&*()_|+\-=?;:'",.<>\{\}\[\]\\\/]/gi, '');//strip off all special characters from video title
        downloadtitle = downloadtitle.replace(/ /g,"-");//replace spaces with dashes
        downloadtitle = downloadtitle.replace(/-+$|(-)+/g, '$1');//replace multiple dashes with single dash

        var url = window.location.hostname;
        url = "/development"//only for development phase
        url = url+"/download/"+downloadtitle+".html";
        window.location=url;
       }
}
```

But I most be honest, I dont see the point of using ajax and then changing the location of the actual page.
Maybe you should start the download in another window?